# Searching for some Chrome extension for fast redirecting the GitHub ipynb page to Google colab pages

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I convert the GitHub ipynb file address to colab address manually as you can see below:

[image]

So i searching for some opensource chrome extension to change its code and do it on it and publish it as new chrome extension for this propose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my `colab.to` redirection to shorten it.

For example, this URL

```
https://github.com/So-AI-love/Classification-of-Heart-Sound/blob/master/pcg_ML.ipynb
```

You can replace `github.com` with just `colab.to` and get

```
https://colab.to/So-AI-love/Classification-of-Heart-Sound/blob/master/pcg_ML.ipynb
```

You can shorten if further by removing `blob/master` and get

```
https://colab.to/So-AI-love/Classification-of-Heart-Sound/pcg_ML.ipynb
```

Comment: Thanks,  I google the `colab.to redirection` ([link](https://www.google.com/search?q=colab.to+redirection&oq=colab.to+redirection&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)) But don't know which one is yours !?

Comment: The whole domain name is mine. I write the redirection code with cloudflare worker. There is no documentation yet, even if you google for it.